# GNU/Linux audio input/ouput synchronization Python

Tags: python, audio

I want to prototype a audio signal processing application in Python and it would be ideal to synchronize input and output streams. That is, I want to know which sample in the input stream was captured at the same time that a given sample in the output stream was played. Whether this is possible or not depends on my audio chipset:  82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller . Even if the hardware does not support sample-accurate synchronization, I'd still like a solution that gets me close.

My platform is GNU/Linux.

I've used PyAudio (bindings to PortAudio) to do playback and capture at the same time, but I don't know how to synchronize the input and output streams.

I know that I can generate a test signal, play it, and correlate it with the input to fine the delay -- that's not the approach I'd like.